# Flask can't figure a way to prevail redirect

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I have an external service, let's call it authenticator.net, which takes care of authenticating users through a login form. Now my flask app needs this authenticator.net service. Here is how it works:

1. Flask decorator 'middleware' redirects to authenticator.net if no `is_logged` session var is found with the `request.url` to go to when logged in.
2. authenticator.net receives a querystring parameter `redirect_to` which redirects to when credentials are valid in the authenticator.net login form.
3. The Flask middleware gets a `jwt` querystring that needs to be decoded with a secret key, if it's valid then set the session var `is_logged` to True and redirect to the original `request.url` the user wanted to visit before being not logged in.

This is not working for some reasons, the original `request.url` is lost in all this process because the middleware is accessed 2 times and Flask is making a weird GET to my application home with query parameter I assume come from authenticator.net but I don't know why Flask makes that request and only on certain cases.

Has anyone worked with external authentication services in Flask ?